# PHP - Return display just text "Array"

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I've got a function to display some result from database, it looks like:

```
 public function getSolicData() {
        $tempArray = $this->solicStringConvert();
        foreach ($tempArray as $key => $solic){
            $success = false;
            try{
                $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
                $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM solic_code WHERE manufacturer = :manufacturer_code AND main_type = :main_type AND option_code = :option_code";
                $stmt_solic = $con->prepare( $sql );
                $stmt_solic->bindValue( "manufacturer_code", "06", PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt_solic->bindValue( "main_type", "50", PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt_solic->bindValue( "option_code", $tempArray[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt_solic->execute();
                $i= 0;
                while ($row = $stmt_solic->fetch()){
                    $this->values[] = $row['description'];                      
                }
            }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                echo $con->errorInfo();
            }

        }
        var_dump($this->values);
        return $this->values;
    }
```

In my eyes it looks good and should return multiple result, problem is it just display just blanked row with text "Array" , but if i try to write var_dump just before it, result of it is:

```
array(17) { [0]=> string(12) "2-DVÉŘOVÝ" [1]=> string(20) "STŘEŠNÍ OKNO MECH" [2]=> string(23) "TÓNOVANÁ SKLA ZELENÁ" [3]=> string(20) "VNĚ-ZRCÁTKA NASTAV" [4]=> string(22) "BEZ ČERVENÉ OZD-LIŠ" [5]=> string(20) "REGUL SKLONU SVĚTEL" [6]=> string(13) "POTAHY LÁTKA" [7]=> string(18) "SEDADLO L V-NASTAV" [8]=> string(22) "ČALOUN PŘÍSTR-DESKY" [9]=> string(14) "1,8 L 66KW RP" [10]=> string(17) "PŘEVOD 4+E-RYCHL" [11]=> string(14) "SERVOŘÍZENÍ" [12]=> string(17) "PNEU 185/55 VR 15" [13]=> string(18) "DISKY 6 J X 15 ALU" [14]=> string(12) "OD SRPNA
```

So i completly don't understand this. To say true i have not clue how to debug this. Is there a chance somebody can help me?
(I can't use echo in my case)

Comment: It's because you cannot echo an Array without specifying the key try to echo it like this: `echo $yourArrayVariable[0]`

Comment: The array is fine. You can't echo or print arrays. You have to use print_r or use a foreach loop to print each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an array, you need to iterate each item to print each one or do something with it.

One way of doing this is to use a foreach loop. But a for loop or while loop could work.

```
foreach($this->values as $value) {
    print $value;
}
```

Alternatively you can access specific values using the index e.g. `print $this->value[0]` will give you the first item.

You can not simply print array or echo it as it is.

You could also use `print_r`. It all depends what you want to do.

Comment: Or use `print_r` or `var_dump`

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loops or for loops and iterate to get the values

Comment: Why not a while or do while loop? Very minimal answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you try echo getSolicData(). You need use foreach or display row of array. Sth like:

```
$res = getSolicData();
echo $res[0];
// or
foreach($res as $row) {
echo $row . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I can't use echo, because if i use echo it fail my HTML where i need to write it.